# How to listen for Project deletes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a project with an incremental builder. The builder writes into a model representations of all resources and their changes, given that the project has a certain nature. This runs pretty well. But the incremental builder is not called if a whole project is deleted from the workspace. What is the best way to create an event handler for that?

I know that I could create an `IResourceChangeListener` and attach it to all projects with my nature. But than I would have to start my plugin with the start of the IDE and that is rather messy.

So, what is the best way to catch "Project deleted" events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IResourceChangeListener` is the way to do this. You don't attach it to projects, it always gets called for all changes.

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to get your plug-in started during Eclipse startup.

Comment: But isn't that discouraged? It would load my whole project at startup. I hoped for a more beautiful solution.

Comment: Well, I knew that IResourceChangeListener would be the thing to use. I actually came looking for a more precise answer. The IResourceChangeListener is a very versatile swiss army knife. I always have to lookup / figure out precisel how to pare it down to the change events I'm interested in. So let me contribute a code snippet to this answer :-)

Comment: @Kris Editing an answer like that is not appropriate despite the robo-reviewers who approved it. Add your own answer if you want to show example code.

Comment: Actually I was going to do that, but then I thought it might be better to try and improve the existing accepted answer instead. But sure, if you feel strongly about 'owning' your answer I'll not modify or try to improve it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an IResourceChangeListener to receive notifications about changes in the workspace. The IResourceChangelistener API is very versatile and can give you change info about many different kinds of changes. Here's an example of how you can use it specifically to detect project deletion.

```
public class ProjectDeletionListenerManager implements IResourceChangeListener {

    public interface ProjectDeletionListener {
        void projectAboutToBeDeleted(IProject project);
    }

    private IWorkspace workspace;
    private ProjectDeletionListener listener;

    public ProjectDeletionListenerManager(ProjectDeletionListener listener) {
        this.workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        this.listener = listener;
        this.workspace.addResourceChangeListener(this, 
                IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_DELETE);
    }

    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        IResource rsrc = event.getResource();
        if (rsrc instanceof IProject) {
            listener.projectAboutToBeDeleted((IProject) rsrc);
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        if (listener!=null) {
            workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(this);
            listener = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Note: code snippet based on [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-commons/blob/e1f9df41af4744e0976c11a415129025ef0a2ad3/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core/src/org/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/frameworks/core/workspace/ProjectDeletionListenerManager.java).